# Объект JS или БД ? Где хранить информацию?

Tags: база-данных, разработка-игр, веб-программирование, объекты

**Предисловие:** В общем появилось много свободного времени. Решил заняться изучением веб-разработки. До этого плотно не сталкивался с ней. Всегда учусь, создавая попутно какой-то большой проект, охватывающий как можно больше. В этот раз решил веб-игру написать. Но не суть.

Стал вопрос. Есть в ней некие объекты, которые дают бонусы при взаимодействие с ними. Объектов таких много, на каждом уровне(относительно-случайным образом) используется лишь некая их часть. И вот стал вопрос. Где хранить данные об этом объекте, варианты такие.

1. В JS(возможно отдельным файлом) создать объект, где ключ ID башни, а значение объект со всеми важными данными о ней. Но решение мне не очень. Как-то неизящно.
2. Хранить все в БД и отправлять все такой же объект в JSON, но уже только с нужными объектами. И так на каждый уровень.

И собственно вопрос. Какой вариант лучше? Либо есть вариант еще лучше?

Вопрос более учебный чем практический. Поэтому прошу по возможности разъяснить почему так или иначе лучше.

Comment: БД - усложнение, оно оправдано если в этом месте у вас есть точка вариативности.